# check multiple sequence in log file

Tags: java, logic

I need to do a analysis on very large no of logs. I need to check if all the events are in a sequence among predefined list of sequence .

I am looking to do this in java.

Any help!!

Comment: I would read the files, performing a merge sort of the events to check the sequences are as you require.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should look at an event processing framework such as [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/).